# Firefox workaround for MediaStreamTrack.getCapabilites()

Tags: javascript, firefox

As the title explains it all, is there any form of workaround to get device capabilites from `MediaStream` for **Firefox**? When ever the `MediaStreamTrack.prototype.getCapabilites()` gets called, firefox will error because the function doen't exist. It's just odd that firefox is the only one (except for IE) where it doesn't support it and a lot of research suggests to use it for applying constraints to it combined with information from `navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints()` method if you get what I mean.

Another thing is that there is not a lot of information about this being an issue. Trust me I've searched on Google to find if anyone else was talking about it and I got nothing from it.

[image: browser support]

```js
// This is just an example:
async function getDeviceCapabilites(constraints) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then((stream) => {
        let track = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
        let cap = track.getCapabilities();    // < ---- This errors in firefox 'getCapabilites() is not a function'
        console.log("Device Capabilities: ", cap);
    });
}

getDeviceCapabilities({audio: true, video: false});
```

Comment: What is the reason for wanting the capabilities?  Specifically what part of that data do you need, and why?  It's not weird at all that Firefox is the only one that doesn't support this API.  Opera and Edge are both Chromium based.  Firefox is the only other full-featured modern browser that's truly cross platform.  There's bound to be some differences.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1179084

Comment: I want it for comparison so any constraints applied using the `applyConstraints()` method won't exceed the device's capabilities. It's for a fun project I'm working on plus it's also just out of curiosity.

Comment: Ideally, you'd set your constraints with their min/max/ideal values when you call `getUserMedia()` and just work with what you get back from the system.  Unless you have an edge use case, this will get you by.  Beyond that, there's probably not much you can do here without Firefox support.  You can always detect what the browser supports and have fallback capability.